# Company email or Domain name based email address validation in Yii

Tags: yii, yii-components

Some times **Yii Email validation** show error message when we use **domain name based email or company email address**. how to fix it in yii framework?

Comment: That's strange.  What, exactly, is the message you're getting, and what's an example of an email address that's having trouble? (Please don't post someone's actual email address).

Comment: It would also be interesting to see the rule firing off `CEmailValidator`. Could you possibly update your question to contain the relevant line out of your model's `rules()` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use your own custom validation rule for e-mail addresses using [regular expression](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh17).

Comment: array('email', 'match', 'pattern'=>'/^[\w\s,]+$/', 'message'=>'only contain word characters.') - like this?

Comment: A regular expression proposed doesn't look like the one to validate e-mail - it doesn't contain `@` character, at least. [Yii validates e-mails](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.14/framework/validators/CEmailValidator.php#L24) according to [RFC 5322](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4). If you are not satisfied by this implementation and can't compose convenient validation pattern by yourself you could look for simplified regular expression that fits your needs, i.e. [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) (see `Trade-Offs in Validating Email Addresses`).